# Empty iframe in jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have grab of some html page from outside of my domain and I would like to show it in jQuery dialog but content in iframe is empty. I am including some foreign css styles soo html content must be in iframe.
Here is JS code.

```
var text = '<label>TEST Text</label><img src="/somaimage.jpg">';

var helpWrapper = document.createElement('div');
helpWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'help_wrapper');

var helpModal = document.createElement('iframe');
helpModal.setAttribute('id', 'help_iframe');

helpWrapper.appendChild(helpModal);

document.body.appendChild(helpWrapper);
helpModal.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
var helpBase = helpModal.contentDocument.createElement("base");
helpBase.setAttribute("href", "https://www.outsidedomain.com");
helpModal.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(helpBase);
var iframedoc = helpModal.contentDocument || helpModal.contentWindow.document;
iframedoc.body.innerHTML = text;
// 1. test
jQuery("#help_wrapper").dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  modal: true
});
// 2. test
jQuery("#help_wrapper").html(helpModal);
```

What am I dooing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some experiments I got solution which is very simple. In first step dialog must prepared and ready for content. After that content should be insert it inside.
Like this working code:

```
var $dialog = jQuery('<div />').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  closeText: "",
  close: function (event, ui) {
    if ($dialog) {
      $dialog.dialog("close");
      $dialog.remove();
    }
  }
});
var helpIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
helpIframe.setAttribute('id', 'help_iframe');

$dialog.append(helpIframe);

helpIframe.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

var helpBase = document.createElement("base");
helpBase.setAttribute("href", "https://www.outsidedomain.com");
helpIframe.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(helpBase);
helpIframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = text;

$dialog.dialog('open');
```